# Prove that $V=\{y \in U |$ exists a path to $x_0$ in U $\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R^2}$. Let $x_0 \in U$. Prove that $V=\{y \in U |$ exists a path to $x_0$ in U $\}$ is open.

**My attempt** Let $z \in V$, I need to find a $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(z) \subset V$. Since $z \in V$ then $ z\in U$ and $\exists$ $\sigma:[0,1] \rightarrow U $ continuous such that $\sigma(0)=z$, $\sigma(1)=x_0$. Since $z \in U$ exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(z) \subset U$. So what I understand is $B_{\epsilon}(z) \subset V$ but I don't understand how use $\sigma$. Could you guide me? please.

Comment: minor note: you have written $U \in \Bbb R^2$ when you probably mean $U \subset \Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $U$ is open, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(z) \subseteq U$. We can show that $B_\epsilon(z) \subseteq V$ as well.

I will sketch the proof informally. Given $w \in B_\epsilon(z)$, consider the straight line path from $w$ to $z$, call it $\gamma$. Then there is a path from $w$ to $x_0$, which is the joining of the paths $\gamma$ and $\sigma$: we first go from $w$ to $z$ via $\gamma$, then we go from $z$ to $x_0$ via $\sigma$. Thus, $w \in V$ as well.

Can you fill in the details?

Comment: In this case $\gamma(0)=w$ and $\gamma(1)=z$, $\sigma(0)=z$ and $\sigma(1)=x_0$. But can I define $f(x)=(1- x)\gamma(0)+x\sigma(1)$?

Comment: sorry , $f(x)=(1- x)\gamma(x)+x\sigma(x)$? $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: @Aaron Not quite. $f$ should be as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\gamma(2x), &\text{if $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$} \\
\sigma(2x - 1), &\text{if $\frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Aaron by the way, I noticed that you don't accept answers in your questions. If you think my answer is helpful, you can click on the checkmark below the voting buttons.